# React/Shopify: How to pass frontend data to server to do PUT request/update api data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, shopify

I am able to successfully access my API data and now I have to change it. In my component I am able to log the data with this code. In my app, there is an input field wherein I type a name to change my product's name and then choose a product once you click a button. `selectedExport` is the ID of the product and `props.inputValue` is the input field. Directory is store-test/web/frontend/components/ProductsModal.jsx

```
const handleSelect = () => {
    console.log(selectedExport) // id of the product
    console.log(props.inputValue); // inputed name for the product name to be changed to
    handleModalChange();
    handleSelectedExport([]);
    handleSelectedExportAs([]);
  };
```

How do I pass this data to my server file? I have this in my server file to update the API and I'm assuming I should change `/api/2022-10/products/id`, and value of `product.id` and `product.title`. Directory is store-test/web/index.js. This is a child component of index.jsx at store-test/web/frontend/pages/index.jsx

```
app.get(`/api/2022-10/products/id`, async (req, res) => { // how to change ID
    const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(
      req,
      res,
      app.get("use-online-tokens")
    );
    const { Product } = await import(
      `@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/${Shopify.Context.API_VERSION}/index.js`
    );

    const product = new Product({session: session})
    product.id = 632910392; // how to pass product id of chosen product
    product.title = "New product title"; // how to pass new product name

    const saveProduct = await product.save({
      update: true,
    });
    res.status(200).send(saveProduct);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but to register an App with the store, with permission to write_products, and then pass your ID and new title via an App Proxy you can setup. With that, you can accept front-end changes, and make them stick. The App Proxy works because Shopify intercepts your PUT (actually you'd use a POST but whatever) and securely packages it and then Shopify hits your App endpoint you informed Shopify about when you setup the Proxy. Hence the word proxy.

Comment: Can you point a specific tutorial for it? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/app-proxies

Comment: Ahh I meant specifically updating the API but I guess I'll start from here

Comment: I have set up an App Proxy. How do I 'pass my ID and new title'?

Comment: Just do the ajax call to the proxy endpoint with your data. What did you think you'd do?